# Same function working for each HTML video individually

Tags: javascript, html, dom, video, html5-video

I wanted to ask for help with the JavaScript function that is supposed to pause and play video on my homepage. So far it controls only one video but I would like to scale it up and make it work for multiple videos my landing page accommodates. Still, individually - each video has its control button and each pause and play affects only the particular video, not all of them at the same time.

HTML

```
<video
 id="heroVideo"></video>
 <button id="playPauseButton">
  <i id="playControl" class="fa-regular fa-circle-play fa-xl"></i>
  <i id="pauseControl" class="fa-regular fa-circle-pause fa-xl"></i>
 </button>
```

JavaScript

````
// VIDEO CONTROLS START
const video = document.getElementById("heroVideo"),
  pauseControl = document.getElementById("pauseControl"),
  playControl = document.getElementById("playControl"),
  playPauseButton = document.getElementById("playPauseButton");
  
function updateControls() {
  if (video.paused) {
    playPauseButton.classList.remove("pause");
    playPauseButton.classList.add("play");
    pauseControl.style.display = "none";
    playControl.style.display = "unset";
    video.removeAttribute("controls");
  } else {
    playPauseButton.classList.remove("play");
    playPauseButton.classList.add("pause");
    pauseControl.style.display = "unset";
    playControl.style.display = "none";
  }
} 
    
video.addEventListener('pause', updateControls);
video.addEventListener('play', updateControls);

playPauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
});
// VIDEO CONTROLS END```


I tried to set multiple consts, each for a different video and then cloning the video attributes for each of those as well as separating it into the same but differently labelled functions but that did not seem to me like the right solution.
````